# Getting The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL when running massive test scenarios in azure pipline using Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, nunit

I am getting timeout issue in azure I am running my regression suite let's assume that it will take 4 hours run in azure pipeline but only after 2 hours all remaining scenarios will get an invalid session id or timeout issue

btw, here's the structure of my per each scenario

```
[TestFixture]
class ScenarioOne{
[OneTimeSetup]
void Setup{
...
}
[OneTimeTeardown]
void Teardown{
...
}
[Test,Order(0)]
void Test1{
..test here
}
[Test,Order(1)]
void Test2{
..test here
}
}
```

each scenario have the same structure and I'm using Nunit on this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Hi @Noob, have you tried using self-hosted agent with `interactive mode`? Does it work for you? Please have a try, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following ways:

1. Try the tests on your local machine to see if the same issue occurs. If the tests can work on your local machine, install a self-hosted agent on the machine to run your pipeline to see if the issue still exists.
2. Try adding the **`no-sandbox`** option to the Chrome.

   ```
   options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
   ```
3. Try creating the Chrome driver differently and specifying a timeout for it, and increasing the page load timeout.

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceName);
   options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

   ChromeDriver drv = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
   drv.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
   ```

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT thank you for you reply unfortunately the codes you mentioned above are already included in my browser initialization yet I'm still getting the timeout error.

Comment: Hi @Noob, have you tried run the tests on your local machine, for example via the Visual Studio, to see if the tests can work? If it can work on your local machine, I recommend that you can install a self-hosted agent on your local machine to run the pipeline. And you can configure the agent to run as **`interactive mode`**. In most cases for Web tests and UI tests, using a self-hosted agent with **`interactive mode`** is the best choice. For more details, see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service).